# How to avoid rerender on clearMarkers at MarkerClusterer?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, googlemapsjs-markerclusterer

I am using https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclusterer/index.html to display and cluster markers on a google map.

I load it using CDN `<script src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclusterer/dist/index.min.js"></script>`.

When I create the markerCLuster like this:

```
  clusti = new  markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ markers, map , renderer});
```

Then all marker are shown. When I remove the markers afterwards, the map is empty.

```
clusti = new  markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ markers, map , renderer});
clusti.clearMarkers();
```

I would like to clear the markers, but not rerender the map. Meaning, I would like to keep the old markers on the map until I have added new markers.

From the docs this should be possible

https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclusterer/classes/MarkerClusterer.html#clearMarkers

[image]

However, when I call

```
clusti = new  markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ markers, map , renderer});
clusti.clearMarkers({noDraw: true});
```

the markers are still gone. So it seems that render() has been called again? What am I missing?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  Don't post just pictures of code., see [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Try `clusti.clearMarkers(true);` instead of `clusti.clearMarkers({noDraw: true});`